# how to fetch top 9 and others based on count(entity_id) sorted highest top 9 and then club the other count into 'others' category

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

The following query executes everything:

```
SELECT count(entity_id), cim.institute_id, cfi.name_ FROM ci_certification_students cis INNER JOIN ci_certification_master cim ON cis.certificate_id = cim.certificate_id
INNER JOIN ci_finalized_institute cfi ON cfi.institute_id=cim.institute_id
WHERE cis.status_id=4 AND cim.institute_id is not null group by cim.institute_id order by count(entity_id) desc limit 100;
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT seqnum,institute_id, (CASE WHEN seqnum > 9 THEN 'others' ELSE name_ END) as name_, sum(total_certi) FROM 
(select count(cis.entity_id) as total_certi, cim.institute_id, cfi.name_ as certiName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(cis.entity_id) desc) as seqnum
FROM certificationdb.ci_certification_students cis 
INNER JOIN ci_certification_master cim ON cis.certificate_id = cim.certificate_id
INNER JOIN certificationdb.ci_finalized_institute cfi ON cim.institute_id=cfi.institute_id
WHERE cis.status_id=4 AND cim.institute_id is not null group by cim.institute_id ORDER BY 
count(cis.entity_id)desc)c GROUP BY (CASE WHEN seqnum> 9 THEN 'others' ELSE name_ END)
ORDER BY seqnum;
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: can you give a copy of your data

Comment: count(entity_id) institute_id name_
8403 62 smartSense Research Institute
687 154 smartSense Plazma Research Center
526 131 Grantham Insitute 1
352 1 asnew qwe
243 5 IIM Banglore - Test123
184 163 Tea Post GIFT City
132 2 Grantham Institute
113 14 IIT-G
108 175 Verified User Institutes
90 4 Gujarat Institute Koln
88 58 Millennial Institute
75 8 Nirma College1
75 3 IIT Mumbai Maharashtra
60 56 Smartsense consulting solution pvt ltd
60 22 granthum Institute
55 54 smartsenses org
42 63 smartSense 001

Comment: In the question? It would help to have the create and insert statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` and two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN seqnum < 10 THEN institute_id END) as institute_id,
       (CASE WHEN seqnum < 10 THEN name_ ELSE 'OTHERS' END) as name,
       SUM(cnt) as cnt
FROM (SELECT cim.institute_id, cfi.name_, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ci_certification_students cis INNER JOIN 
           ci_certification_master cim
           ON cis.certificate_id = cim.certificate_id INNER JOIN
           ci_finalized_institute cfi ON 
           cfi.institute_id = cim.institute_id
      WHERE cis.status_id = 4 AND cim.institute_id is not null
      GROUP BY cim.institute_id, cfi.name_
     ) c
GROUP BY institute_id, name
ORDER BY MIN(seqnum);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon ..I made a few changes in the above query and got my expected...Thanks a lot...!